# pythonでtaggeddocumentが階段のような構造で出力される

Tags: python, 自然言語処理

**使用環境**
jupyternotebook
windows10

言葉では非常に説明しづらいので出力結果を見ていただきたいです。

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument

import MeCab
import csv

mt = MeCab.Tagger()

reports = []
with open("allcomment.tsv",mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # reports.tsvには一行にID,文章がtab区切りで保存されている
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for report_id, report in reader:
        words = []
        node = mt.parseToNode(report)
        while node:
            if len(node.surface) > 0:
                words.append(node.surface)
            node = node.next
        stopword = ['評価','使用','デザイン','配慮','商品','形状','機能','機能' '使用', 'ほとんど','W']
        words2 = [token for token in words if token not in stopword]
        # wordsが文章の単語のリスト,tagsには文章IDを指定
        reports.append(TaggedDocument(words=words2, tags=[report_id]))
        print(reports)
```

出力結果

```
[TaggedDocument(words=['過剰', '装飾', '重視', '考慮', '新しい', 'レンズ', 'フレーム', '関係', '出来', '軽量', '掛け', '心地', '技術', '反映', '真面目', '眼鏡', '印象', '受ける', 'フレーム', '視界', '妨げ', 'サイドリブ', '特徴', '外観', '生かし', '美しい', '形体', '眼鏡', 'フレーム', '新しい', '印象', '生み出し'], tags=['1'])]
[TaggedDocument(words=['過剰', '装飾', '重視', '考慮', '新しい', 'レンズ', 'フレーム', '関係', '出来', '軽量', '掛け', '心地', '技術', '反映', '真面目', '眼鏡', '印象', '受ける', 'フレーム', '視界', '妨げ', 'サイドリブ', '特徴', '外観', '生かし', '美しい', '形体', '眼鏡', 'フレーム', '新しい', '印象', '生み出し'], tags=['1']), TaggedDocument(words=['眼鏡', 'フレーム', '求め', '要素', '調和', '新しい', 'レンズ', '留め', 'パーツ', '新しく', '開発', 'いかさ', 'オール', 'チタン', '製', 'あたたか', '材質', '生かし', '印象', '受ける'], tags=['2'])]
[TaggedDocument(words=['過剰', '装飾', '重視', '考慮', '新しい', 'レンズ', 'フレーム', '関係', '出来', '軽量', '掛け', '心地', '技術', '反映', '真面目', '眼鏡', '印象', '受ける', 'フレーム', '視界', '妨げ', 'サイドリブ', '特徴', '外観', '生かし', '美しい', '形体', '眼鏡', 'フレーム', '新しい', '印象', '生み出し'], tags=['1']), TaggedDocument(words=['眼鏡', 'フレーム', '求め', '要素', '調和', '新しい', 'レンズ', '留め', 'パーツ', '新しく', '開発', 'いかさ', 'オール', 'チタン', '製', 'あたたか', '材質', '生かし', '印象', '受ける'], tags=['2']), TaggedDocument(words=['視力', '矯正', '及び', 'サングラス', '歳', '代', '歳', '代', '対象', '若者', '自分', 'ファッション', 'あわせる', '個性', '掛け', 'つくり', '良', '売り', '考慮', '新しい', '試み', '見'], tags=['3'])]
```

上記のように[(1)],[(1,2)],[(1,2,3)]...と出力されます。
このデータを用いてDoc2vecでモデルを作成したいのですが、この状態の
'reports'をモデル作成に用いても問題はないのでしょうか？
問題があるとすれば、最後の[(1,2,3...n)]だけを出力するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 階段状？に表示されるのは `print(reports)` が for loop ブロック内に置かれているからではないでしょうか。インデントを for loop と同じ高さにすれば最終結果のみ表示されるはずです。

Comment: `gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec()` の API を見ますと、`documents: iterable of list of class "gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument"` と書かれていますので、`reports` を渡しても問題ないかと思います。`model = Doc2Vec(documents=reports, ...)`

Comment: ありがとうございます、metropolisさんのおかげで研究が日々少しずつ進んでいます。。。